# Hover эффект на изображении в виде полупрозрачного треугольника

Tags: html, css, hover

Пробовал делать при наведении из border, но не получалось разместить ровно треугольник, он вылазил за пределы изображения (сложность в том что изображение не квадратное. Пробовал через :before :after - не получалось. в голове только вариант взять из макета этот ховер-фильтр и при наведении добавлять его. Подскажите пожалуйста , может есть другой способ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

[Поддержка браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

```css
.img-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img-container > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.img-container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-ribbon");
    clip-path: url("#clip-ribbon");
    transition: .3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.img-container:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/300/arch" />
</div>
<svg width='0' height='0'>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-ribbon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0 0, 0 1, 1 1" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

С градиентом как-то так получается.

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
.img-container:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(184,225,252,0.3) 0%,rgba(186,234,252,0.3) 49.99999%,rgba(186,234,252,0) 50%,rgba(189,243,253,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/100/arch"/></div>
<div class="img-container"><img src="https://placeimg.com/230/100/arch"/></div>
```

в двух словах - градиент из двух цветов, с резкой границей, `to top right` дает диагональ в любом блоке.